# Admin catalog -> Manage products grid not showing

Tags: upgrade, enterprise-1.14, product-grid, ee-1.14.2.4

**After upgrade from 1.14.2.4 to 1.14.3.1, product grid in admin side is not showing products.** The page just opens blank.

No clues why this is happening.
The console is clean, not showing any error. Even after enabling error reporting, its not showing any PHP error too.

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared all your caches? Logged out and logged in again?

Comment: yes, several times

Comment: please check your log files

Comment: I renamed current exception.log and system.log files and refreshed the page. No new files were generated, means there is nothing to log in exception.log and system.log files regarding this issue.

Comment: Please enable error log in index.php file. following change in index.php file

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

to

error_reporting(E_ALL);

Set $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true

and uncomment this line

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

and check again

Comment: @Abdul, I did all the three things but the page is still blank.

Comment: have you got any error in admin side?

Comment: Nope, no any error in admin, neither in system.log
All the other sections/extensions everything else is working fine, except this product grid

Comment: any third party extension in your site that affacted product grid? if than disable that extension

Answer (score -1):

Please uncomment the line from index.php file,

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);